# how to display the dynamic data like stock data using ionic 2/3

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

Hi im getting the dynamic data in the below format

```
{
  "Persons": [
    {
      "CName": "TestOne",
      "CId": 32,
      "UId": 36,
      "Email": "Test@test.com",
      "DeviceId": "822278EC",
      "Color":"#008000"
      "Value":65.65
    },
    {
      "CName": "TestTwo",
      "CId": 33,
      "UId": 37,
      "Email": "Friends@test.com",
      "DeviceId": "822278EC",
      "Color":"#FF0000",
      "Value":-15.65

    }
  ],
  "Name": null,
  "Id": 0,
  "User": 0

}
```

Here what i want to do is i want to display the dynamic data in cards in the below format

[image]

here i can able to display the dynamic data in the form of cards but how can i display color to the cards based positive value and negative value . Suppose if i got 35.36 it has to show green color along with that up ward arrow and if i got -36.36 it has to show red color along with down ward arrow

below is my template code

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-card  *ngFor="let cData of CList" (click)="Get(cData)">  
    <ion-card-content>
      <ion-card-title>
        <ion-icon name="contact"></ion-icon>  {{cData.CName}}     
      </ion-card-title>
    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

Till now im showing name only how to show number along with upward or downward icon

Comment: since the color is already in the json, does it need to be calculated or simply used from the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think all you need to do is compare the value , like `*ngIf='cData.value >= 0'` and `*ngIf='cData.value < 0'`

```
<ion-content>

    <ion-card  *ngFor="let cData of CList" (click)="Get(cData)">  

        // This block will be shown if value is positive (design it as per requirement)
        <ion-card-content *ngIf='cData.value >= 0'>
            <ion-card-title>
                <ion-icon name="contact"></ion-icon>  {{cData.CName}}     
            </ion-card-title>
        </ion-card-content>

        // This block will be shown if value is negative (design it as per requirement)
        <ion-card-content *ngIf='cData.value < 0'>
            <ion-card-title>
                <ion-icon name="contact"></ion-icon>  {{cData.CName}}     
            </ion-card-title>
        </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>

</ion-content>
```

Comment: so i have to use temp variable  in ion-card content  and have to write on ion-card   *ngFor="let cData of CList"

Comment: Yes that would be enough.

Comment: This code will work you can directly check that , simply replace your block with mine

Comment: Normally what u said is true here i have  to display **TestOne** & **TestTwo** both increase and decrease at the same time here both items i have to show not one item

Answer (score 1):

try below this and let me know what you get

```
    <ion-content>
      <div *ngFor="let cData of CList" (click)="Get(cData)">
      <ion-card [ngClass]="(cData.value > 0) ? 'positiveColor':'negativeColor'"  [style.background-color]="cData.Color">  


          {{cData.name}} &nbsp;&nbsp; {{cData.CName}}     
         <ion-icon name="contact" item-end></ion-icon>

      </ion-card>
      </div>
    </ion-content>
```

.scss file

```
.positiveColor{
  color: white;
}
.negativeColor{
  color: white;
}
```

Comment: im getting the Color Code Dynamically and i have to apply that code only to the card.. and i am displaying the data in the ion-cards not button

Answer (score 1):

You can use `[style.background]` and bind your property `Color` to it:

```html
<ion-card  *ngFor="let cData of CList" [style.background]="cData.Color">  
  <!-- -->
</ion-card>
```

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-dgs5cv?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.ts)**